# How to obtain hexadecimal value of -nan

Tags: c++, floating-point, nan

I am writing some code in intel intrinsics and did this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

float data[4];
__m128 val1 = _mm_set_ps1(2);
__m128 val2 = _mm_set_ps1(1);
val1 = _mm_cmpgt_ps(val1, val2);
_mm_store_ps(data, val1);

std::cout << std::hex << data[0];
```

I am trying to get the hexadecimal value of "true" in SSE intrinsics (which is -nan), but only keep getting -nan as "the hexadecimal value" whenever I try to print the hexadecimal value of -nan.

I also tried using std::oct and std::dec and neither of those worked.

I also tried comparing 0xFFFFFFFF and data[0] in different combinations and got this:

```
float data[4];
__m128 val1 = _mm_set_ps1(2);
__m128 val2 = _mm_set_ps1(1);
val1 = _mm_cmpgt_ps(val1, val2);
_mm_store_ps(data, val1);

float f = 0xFFFFFFFF;
float g = 0xFFFFFFFF;
std::cout << std::dec << (data[0] == f) << "\n"; // Prints "0"

std::cout << std::dec << (data[0] == data[0]) << "\n"; // Prints "0"

std::cout << std::dec << (f == g); // Prints "1"
```

Is there any way for me to print the hexadecimal value of -nan and if not, can somebody please tell me the binary, hexadecimal, etc. value of -nan?

Comment: Generate quiet NaN. Returns a quiet NaN (Not-A-Number) value of type double . The NaN values are used to identify undefined or non-representable values for floating-point elements, such as the square root of negative numbers or the result of 0/0.

Comment: How could something which isn't a number (you do know that "nan" stands for "not a number"?) have a value? It might have an implementation defined value, but that's really besides the point I think.

Comment: The result of a 32bit float comparison is 0xFFFFFFFF or 0, to enable being used as a mask. That's accidentally also -nan. Are you interested in the value only or specifically in printing it with code?

Comment: @Harold I get "4.29497e+09" when I try to print 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Actually it has some value which is interpreted as nan. Punn it the the unsigned integer of the size of float and print this integer instead

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think OP looks for the binary value that represents NaN. And that do exist. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @4386427 While there exists such a value, it's not really part of the C++ standard and therefore is not portable. There's really no reason to rely on that, when one could (and should!) use [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan). Especially considering that there could be multiple possible values that represents  `nan` or `-nan`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP is using SIMD intrinsics here, portability went out the window a while ago

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Oh, I didn't intend to say that it was part of the C++ standard. It's rather part of the floating point standard used on the specific system. Anyway, the point is that NaN have (at least) one binary pattern that can be printed.

Answer (score 4):

Per IEEE specification, NaN is a floating-point value that has all of its *exponent* bits set to "1".

So a value with *all* the bits set to "1" would also be a NaN.

If you want to see the raw bytes, just print the raw bytes:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
std::string get_hex_bytes(T x) {
    std::stringstream res;
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&x);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i) {
        if (i)
            res << ' ';
        res << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << (int)p[i];
    }
    return res.str();
}

int main() {
    float data = NAN;
    std::cout << get_hex_bytes(data) << std::endl;
}
```

On a little-endian machine will print something like:

```
00 00 c0 ff
```

---

P.S. `float f = 0xFFFFFFFF;` will not set all of the bits to "1", it simply converts an integer `0xFFFFFFFF` to a floating point representation (perfectly representable with some loss of precision).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no such thing as a "negative `nan`". `nan` is, by definition, Not a Number. You can't negate it. `-nan` is the same sort of thing as `nan`.

There's no exactly standards-compliant way to get the underlying bits comprised by a floating-point value, but the closest thing is `memcpy`. Simply copy from a pointer to `float` or `double` to a pointer to an equivalently-sized unsigned integer type, then print that with `std::hex` active.

Comment: But I have an apple, and a -tomato, and when I add them together I get banana.

Answer (score 1):

As the manual says, `_mm_cmpgt_ps` (which is really `cmpps` with a specific comparison predicate),

> Performs a SIMD compare of the packed single-precision floating-point values in the source operand (second
>   operand) and the destination operand (first operand) and returns the results of the comparison to the destination
>   operand. The comparison predicate operand (third operand) specifies the type of comparison performed on each of
>   the pairs of packed values. **The result of each comparison is a doubleword mask of all 1s (comparison true) or all
>   0s (comparison false).** The sign of zero is ignored for comparisons, so that –0.0 is equal to +0.0.

(emphasis added)

"All 1s", or 0xFFFFFFFF in hexadecimal (since it's 32 bits per element), has the sign bit set (so there is a legitimate reason to print a `-` sign in front of whatever else this number might be) and since the exponent is all ones and the significand is not zero, it is also a NaN. The NaN-ness usually isn't very relevant, the main intended use for this result is as a mask in bitwise operations (eg `_mm_and_ps`, `_mm_blendv_ps`, etc), which do not care about the special semantics of NaN.

Comment: When I tried comparing 0xFFFFFFFF and data[0] (the -nan value), it seemed that 0xFFFFFFFF behaved differently than -nan. Could this be because of flags? I posted the code above.

Comment: @Cppplus1 yes, you should follow Sneftels advice and get the result as some sort of integer. Floats act funny, especially NaN, which is not equal to itself.